# Set percentage of column to 0 (pandas)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and I want to set some percentage of a column to 0. Let's say the df has two columns.

```
  A   B  
  1   6
  2   7
  3   8
  4   4
  5   9
```

I now want to set B for the first and last 20 % of the df to 0.

```
  A   B  
  1   0
  2   7
  3   8
  4   4
  5   0
```

Comment: this isn't the first and last 10% - it's the first and last 20%

Comment: sure, thanks! it's just an example for some x percentage, but you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for join first and last positions and then change values by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), for position of column `B` use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
N = .2
total = len(df.index)
#convert to int for always integer
i = int(total * N)
idx = np.r_[0:i, total-i:total]
df.iloc[idx, df.columns.get_loc('B')] = 0
```

Or:

```
N = .2
total = len(df.index)
i = int(total * N)
pos = df.columns.get_loc('B')

df.iloc[:i, pos] = 0
df.iloc[total - i:, pos] = 0
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  7
2  3  8
3  4  4
4  5  0
```

EDIT:

If [`Sparsedataframe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/sparse.html#sparsedataframe) and same type of values is possible convert to numpy array, set value and convert back:

```
arr = df.values
N = .2
total = len(df.index)
i = int(total * N)
pos = df.columns.get_loc('B')
idx = np.r_[0:i, total-i:total]

arr[idx, pos] = 0
print (arr)
[[1 0]
 [2 7]
 [3 8]
 [4 4]
 [5 0]]

df = pd.SparseDataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  7
2  3  8
3  4  4
4  5  0

print (type(df))
<class 'pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>
```

EDIT1:

Another solution is first convert to dense and then convert back:

```
df = df.to_dense()
#apply solution
df = df.to_sparse()
```

Comment: @jkortner - hmmm, it is a bit complicated. One possible solution is convert sparsedataframe to dense by `df = df.to_dense()`, apply solution and then convert back by `df = df.to_sparse()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
x = 20  # percentage of the first and last rows
y = float(len(df.index))
z = int(round(y/100 *x))
h = int(y-z)
df['B'][:z]=0
df['B'][h:]=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
num_rows = round(len(df)*0.2)

df.loc[(df.index<num_rows) | (df.index[::-1]<num_rows), 'B'] = 0

df
Out[89]: 
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  7
2  3  8
3  4  4
4  5  0
```