# Assign values to SparseArray in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have an object of type `SparseDataFrame` and I want to change some values.

Usually when working with dataframes I use `DataFrame.loc`, `DataFrame.iloc` or `set_value`. When trying to use this methods on a `SparseDataFrame` object I always get an error as following:

```
"SparseArray does not support item assignment via setitem"
TypeError: SparseArray does not support item assignment via setitem
```

How do I work with a SparseArray correctly?

This question: [Set percentage of column to 0 (pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030495/9157212)
 suggests to use first `df.to_dense()`, do the assignment and then use `df.to_sparse()` to convert it back.
I wonder if there is a way to work directly with the `SparseDataFrame` / `SparseArray`?

Answer (score 3):

It is frustrating to not be able to insert directly in sparse format with .loc[]. I'm afraid I only have **a workaround**.

Since the original posting of the question (and version 0.25) pandas has deprecated SparseDataFrame. Instead, it created a data type (SparseDtype) that can be applied to individual series within the DataFrame. In other words, it is no longer "all or nothing". You can:

- convert a few columns in your DataFrame to dense format while keeping the others sparse,
- insert your data with .loc[] in the dense columns,
- and then convert these columns back to sparse.

This is obviously *a lot less memory intensive than converting the entire DataFrame to dense*.

Here is a very simple function to illustrate what I mean:

```
def sp_loc(df, index, columns, val):
    """ Insert data in a DataFrame with SparseDtype format

    Only applicable for pandas version > 0.25

    Args
    ----
    df : DataFrame with series formatted with pd.SparseDtype
    index: str, or list, or slice object
        Same as one would use as first argument of .loc[]
    columns: str, list, or slice
        Same one would normally use as second argument of .loc[]
    val: insert values

    Returns
    -------
    df: DataFrame
        Modified DataFrame

    """

    # Save the original sparse format for reuse later
    spdtypes = df.dtypes[columns]

    # Convert concerned Series to dense format
    df[columns] = df[columns].sparse.to_dense()

    # Do a normal insertion with .loc[]
    df.loc[index, columns] = val

    # Back to the original sparse format
    df[columns] = df[columns].astype(spdtypes)

    return df
```

Simple usage example:

```
# DÉFINITION DATAFRAME SPARSE

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['I', 'J'])
df1.loc['a', 'J'] = 0.42
df1 = df1.astype(pd.SparseDtype(float))
#     |   I |      J
# ----+-----+--------
# a   | nan |   0.42
# b   | nan | nan
# c   | nan | nan

df1.dtypes
#I    Sparse[float64, nan]
#J    Sparse[float64, nan]

df1.sparse.density
# 0.16666666666666666

# INSERTION

df1 = sp_loc(df1, ['a','b'], 'I', [-1, 1])
#     |   I |      J
# ----+-----+--------
#  a  |  -1 |   0.42
#  b  |   1 | nan
#  c  | nan | nan

df1.sparse.density()
# 0.5
```